# Slider for non time attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute, timemanager

How to filter data on attributes with a slider?

By example, i would like to filter weights (CHARGE in my layer) attribute for polygons without to change the filter formula.

[image]

The feature is available for time window. I don't know other solutions for non date/time type attributes.

How can i do?

Answer (score 4):

This solution works with time manager. This is a workaround.

I convert one time unit. By example: minutes as the value to slide on.

Here *%M* is the *CHARGE* field to silde on for START and END.

[image]

The minutes in normal usage of Time manager are replaced by the value of *CHARGE* field. In this snapshot, value is 15:

[image: Value is 15]