# Using QGIS Slider for filtering based on attributes?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

For each of my layers, I have various attributes that I might be filtering on, like attribute `A < 1000 AND B > 300` etc..

Just like we can add an opacity slider to the legend, I want to be able to add sliders for the various attributes I am filtering on, without having to go into the filter screen and manually change the filter text.

I have seen this answer:
[Slider for non time attributes in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261409/slider-for-non-time-attributes-in-qgis)

And while the hacky solution does work (use Time Manager), it doesn't really work if you want to have multiple sliders to explore your data.

I'm thinking of making something along these lines, but before I do that I figured it's such a useful feature that perhaps there already is a plugin that does it, or some other mechanism. I couldn't find it.

Comment: The opacity slider in the legend panel is a "legend widget" or "embedded widget in legend." It might help to search based on those terms. I found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/232367/81764) which has some code that was used to create the opacity slider widget. Maybe you can repurpose it to create your own widget.

Comment: In the meantime (IE before you finish developing your plugin), you might find a rule-based style easier to use than a filter.

Comment: Thanks @csk! I do use rule based styles, and they are great, but for data exploration they aren't what I want. The legend widget work definitely started me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I couldn't find anything. So I made it myself. You can find the code [here on github](https://github.com/orcaomar/qgis_range_filters).

I figured out how to do this by starting at this [post on QGIS legend widgets by Richard Duivenvoorde](http://www.qgis.nl/2019/02/14/about-layer-tree-embedded-widgets-and-have-your-wmts-always-crispy-sharp/?lang=en).

In the process, I needed a range slider which didn't really exist in PyQt, so I modified [this one by Ryan Galloway](http://rsgalloway.github.com/qrangeslider).

It still needs a bit of work to turn it into a full plugin. When I do that, I'll update this answer. But it's usable, with some kinks. I've been using it to explore some data, and it has been very helpful with that. You can watch this [video demo of the filter in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FapVK6dpC8&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/legend_data_filter/#plugin-versions

Comment: I want to write a simple widget with only a description and a colored point (legend).
I don't know how to go about it and where to start.
Post on QGIS legend widgets by Richard Duivenvoorde unfortunately does not work but it would help me a lot. Please provide available instructions.